# PHP PDO - doesnt insert all statements in the loop

Tags: php, loops, pdo, percona, handlersocket

Lets imagine situation where we should insert a lot of rows in the loop using PDO.

```php
$sql = "INSERT INTO products (name, price) VALUES (:name, :price)";
$stmt = $db->prepare($sql);

for ($i = 0; $i < 100; $i++)
{
    $name = md5(rand(0, 1000));
    $price = rand(0, 1000);

    $stmt->bindParam(':name', $name);
    $stmt->bindParam(':price', $price);

    try
    {
        $result = $stmt->execute();

        if (!$result)
        {

            print_r($db->errorInfo());
        }

        echo $db->lastInsertId();
    }
    catch (Exception $e)
    {
        echo $e->getMessage();
    }
}
```

In this way all 100 rows will not be inserted to the database. And echo at 23th line will output something like:

> 1 2 3 4 5 ... 59 60 61 61 61 61 61 61

and print_r at 20th line will output

```
 Array (
     [0] => 00000
     [1] => 
     [2] =>  
 )
```

PDO error code 00000 means that everything works fine. And no rows were affected. And if I try to manually insert row on which $result was false - all is ok.

and only 61 rows will be inserted to the table. And each time script is running this number is changing and this is **really strange**.

Why?

In other way - we could make one query from all insert queries and there are all 100 rows will be inserted. Here is a [link](http://pastebin.com/MAMbGVgG) to pastebin with code.

Here is a table structure:

```sql
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `products` (
`id` int(10) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `price` int(10) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

**btw.** I use percona MySQL server (5.5) with HandlerSocker plugin. 
And I tried to insert rows using HandlerSocket. Here is a code

```php
$hs = new \HSPHP\WriteSocket();
$hs->connect();

$id = $hs->getIndexId('test','products','','name,price');
$loops_number = 10000;

for ($i = 0; $i < $loops_number; $i++)
{
    $name = 'handler-'.md5(rand(0, 1000));
    $price = rand(0, 1000);

    $hs->insert($id, array($name, $price));
}
```

And I after this - I have ~ 14000 rows in DB. Why? Also if I change number of loops (variable **$loops_number**) -

```
if 10 loops - I have 100 rows in DB table
if 50 loops - 50 rows
if 100 loops - 100 rows
if 500 loops - 500 rows
if 1000 loops - ~1100 rows and this number always change. (if I truncate table and run script again)
```

Seems problem with my MySQL server?

Comment: there could be any number of reasons why it repeats 61.  It would help to post your actual code. This isnt it, correct?

Comment: You need only prepare the statement once, before the loop. No need to prepare it 100 times :)

Comment: You mean it's always stuck at 61?

Comment: Also I believe you can get more specific info on your errors with errorInfo if you catch PDOException...

Comment: About prepare outside the loop - I know but this will not resolve the problem.

Comment: And this is the final code. i just playing with PDO and use this little script.

Comment: > You mean it's always stuck at 61?  - no. Number of affected rows always change

Comment: Why do you execute 2 Times the query?

Comment: sorry, that was just mistake when editing the question

Comment: Do you have indices on any fields, like `unique` or `primary`? If so, check if `rand` is returning already a value given by previous roles.

Comment: so in this way only one row should not be inserted. But I see now after one row is failed - all next inserts will be failed too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I resolve this problem by reinstalling PHP. (I used PHP from this repo:  `ppa:ondrej/php5`)

And problem with HandlerSocket inserting:
1. create index inside the loop
2. if you make insert query by HandlerSocket better to set id (auto increment) manually

Answer (score 0):

Whoa!!! That is a lot of info to look at bro. Am not sure whether i have got your question right but if I have then the below piece of code will achieve the same effect only better:

```
$name = md5(rand(0, 1000));
$price = rand(0, 1000);

try{

    $db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

    for($i=0, $i<100, $i++){

        $sql = "INSERT INTO products (name, price) VALUES (:name, :price)";
        $stmt = $db->prepare($sql);
        $stmt->execute(array(':name'=>$name[$i], ':price'=>$price[$i]));

        echo $db->lastInsertId();

    }

}catch(PDOException $e){


    print_r($db->errorInfo());

    echo 'An error occured'.$e->getMessage();

}
```

Give it a try and tell me what you got.

Comment: when failed i got this: `Array
(
    [0] => 00000
    [1] => 
    [2] => 
)

An error occuredSQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 2013 Lost connection to MySQL server during query`

Comment: btw. If I run script form browser - is fail. If form console - all is ok. I suppose that problems with nginx + php-fpm?

Comment: is all that necessary or is it a project requirement?

Comment: No. I just play with percona mysql server and found this that is worng. So I want to resolve problem and answer the question "Why is it worng" :)

Comment: if your script works fine-thumbs up. however, you should also consider other ways of doing things, they may give same results but less cumbersome and more efficient. its the beauty of programming ;)

Comment: it works fine only form console :) But form browser - always is failed :(

Comment: Have you tried modifying your code to the code i gave in the answer? If you haven't yet then you should. It may help

Comment: I change my code. And at first comment on your answer I wrote the error I got.

Comment: Haha...should have seen that. the possible reason for that error is that either the query is incorrect or too large. in this case we trying to execute a query 100 times so the most probable reason is that we are sending to the server a very large query.

Comment: `"INSERT INTO products (name, price) VALUES (:name, :price)"`  I believe that this is not large query)

Comment: when you put that in a for loop you expect it to execute 100 times right?

Comment: yeap. I hope to see 100 rows in table

Comment: so those are 100 different queries being run simultaneously. echo it and see what i mean

Comment: Never write `$stmt = $db->prepare($sql);` unless you are changing the prepared statement.  The `prepare()` call should be made before entering the loop.  Only the `execute()` call should be inside the loop.